# How to zoom a matrix that includes NaN values?

Tags: python-3.x, zooming

I have a map (2D matrix) of observations. Grid boxes without an observed value is assigned a NaN value.

I would like to use the zoom function in python to upscale the size of the grid boxes from 1°x1° to 10°x10°. When I do that, I want to ignore NaN values. For example, in an extreme scenario, if I have 100 1°x1° grid boxes where only one 1°x1° grid box contains an observation and the other 99 1°x1° grid boxes contain NaN, then I want the zoomed out 10°x10° to only take on the value of the single 1°x1° grid box that contained an observation.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Let me know if the question is not clear!

Note that it is only in my dataset that the fill value for no observation is NaN. The fill value could be assigned any value. But I want to be able to zoom the grid box sizes with the zooming ignoring the fill values.

Below is an example code that does not do what I want, since the zoom function assigns a NaN value to the 10°x10° grid box if there is one present in the 100 1°x1° it is built from. But I included it as an attempt to illustrate the problem:

```
import numpy.ma as ma
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import zoom

# Create the fake matrix
A = np.random.uniform(0, 10, 10000)
A[A < 5] = np.nan
A = A.reshape(100,100)

# Print the appearance of A
print('A:')
print(A)

# Zoom out to 10 times larger grid boxes
B = zoom(A,(1/10,1/10),order=1)

# Print the appearance of B
print('B:')
print(B)
```

Comment: Do you still have the problem if you use `A[A < 5] = 0` ?

Comment: [Also found this if it helps](http://astrolitterbox.blogspot.com/2012/03/healing-holes-in-arrays-in-python.html)